# How do I remove the OneNote Badge from the Android home screen?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I don't mind OneNote itself, but the badge icon stuck on the edge of the screen gets in the way of some controls in other apps. I know it can be moved, but how do I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [microsoft help page](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Remove-the-OneNote-badge-from-the-Android-homescreen-ad89296a-7186-4891-b9ff-c3fc0968a8bd) describes it quite well.

You might want to remove the notification from the notification tray first, as it's designed to keep the icon there for you.

Simply press and hold the badge, an "X" icon will appear at the bottom of the screen. Drag and drop the badge and you're done.